# How to stub multiple parameter Springboot Restful POST Endpoint using WireMock

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockito, wiremock

I am new to wiremock and trying to stub the invocation of the following springboot restful endpoint.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/template/pdf", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> bindData(
        @ApiParam(value = "BindDataRequest payload", required = true)
        @RequestParam String template, @RequestParam String templateDataAsJson) throws IOException {

   //Some code 
    return ResponseEntity.ok("xyz");
}

**The following basic logic works:**

templatingService.stubFor(
                post(urlEqualTo("/template/pdf"))
                        .willReturn(aResponse().withBody(JSON_INPUT_TO_PDF_GEN).withStatus(200)));
```

But, i need a way of setting the 2 string request parameters before invoking .willReturn(.....)

I have tried :

```
templateBinderService.stubFor(
                post(urlEqualTo("/template/pdf"))
                        .withRequestBody(WireMock.equalTo("jixhcjxhcjxhcxhchx"))
                        .withRequestBody(WireMock.equalTo("nhhhxhxhhhhhxhhhh"))
                        .willReturn(aResponse().withBody(JSON_INPUT_TO_HTML2PDF_GEN).withStatus(200)));
```

But got:

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 Not Found

```
//I have also tried:

templateBinderService.stubFor(
                post(urlEqualTo("/template/test"))
.withRequestBody(containing("param1-value"))
.withRequestBody(containing("param2-value"))

                        .willReturn(aResponse().withBody("i-am-a-response").withStatus(200)));

//I have also tried:

    templateBinderService.stubFor(
                    post(urlEqualTo("/template/test"))
                            .withRequestBody(equalToJson("{}"))
                            .willReturn(aResponse().withBody("i-am-a-response").withStatus(200)));
```

Please help with code snippet or reference.

Answer (score 0):

Since both the parameters `template` and `templateDataAsJson` are annotated with `@RequestParam`, they should be passed accordingly in the wiremock stub as below.

```
templatingService.stubFor(
        post(urlEqualTo("/template/pdf?template=value1&templateDataAsJson=value2"))
       .willReturn(aResponse().withBody(JSON_INPUT_TO_PDF_GEN).withStatus(200)));
```

where `value1` and `value2` are the respective values for both parameters.

Comment: @olatom did this help you?

Comment: Hello Madhu, thanks for the quick response. But that did not work. I am getting a org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 Not Found
I did change the query string to template=a&templateDataAsJson=a", thinking its because of the big encoded html and json params, but no. Am I right in saying query string is for GET Request. How do i send params for a POST request pleasde? That might be the issue.